# Clear variables in Canopy environment

Tags: python, ipython, enthought

Is there a command I can use in a Python file to **clear all variables**?

I've been searching for this for a while but all I could find was to use `%reset`. However, this only seems to work in IPython, but not when I try to run a python file.

FYI, I am working with the free version of enthought canopy.

[ADDED from comments:] I have several python files I run, which might have shared variables. I would like to be able to clear all variables before running any of the files to guarantee that I have defined variables correctly and that they are taking the correct values.

Comment: Please clarify your question. The IPython magic commands are available in the "Python" window but cannot be used within a Python file. Which is it? -- in the Python window, or in a Python file?

Comment: OK, sorry about that.

Comment: I need a command I can use in a **Python file** to delete all variables. 

I am fairly new to Python, and I didn't know what an Ipython magic command was until now. 

I assumed that if it worked in the "Python" window it would work on a Python file, but obviously this is not the case.

Comment: Sounds good. Stack overflow protocol would have you updating your question so that others can search and learn from it and not have to dig into the comments to see what the question really is.

Comment: And by the way, since you are just talking about a Python file, this really is just a python question, nothing special to do with canopy. I'm retagging appropriately.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This was my first post. I will make sure to fix it.

Comment: stepping back... Why do you want to do this? A Python script starts with no variables defined, so has complete control over the variables that are defined in it. It's not like some random variables are going to creep into your module namespace without your knowing it.

Comment: Well, this is why it was important to mention that I am working within the enthought canopy environment. I have several python files I run, which might have shared variables. I would like to be able to clear all variables before running any of the files to guarantee that I have defined variables correctly and that they are taking the correct values.

Comment: Sorry, I just started using Python not too long ago. This is a difficult problem to solve? I would have thought it was just a single command.

Comment: I have edited your question to include what is the heart of your question / assumptions, from your previous comment, and then responded. In the future please try to make your questions more complete, and in particular to make your assumptions and expectations explicit rather than assuming that they are understood and correct. (Granted, as a beginner one doesn't always know which of one's assumptions are problematic!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr -- what you describe is not an issue.

But it is worth understanding, to avoid other points of confusion:

1) When you are running IPython (including Canopy's Python pane, which is a standard IPython QtConsole), IPython has its own global namespace (list of variables and modules and functions etc) which is distinct from the namespace of the scripts which run within it. This can be confusing, but it is actually a feature.

2) When you run each script normally, it starts with an empty namespace, just as if it were running in plain Python. That's why your concern is a non-issue. But this can also confuse beginners, because your script also doesn't know about the modules that have already been imported in IPython. For more on this, see [this article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469630-Modules-are-already-available-in-Canopy-s-Python-PyLab-prompt-but-not-in-a-script).

3) When the script completes, its global namespace is copied into the IPython global namespace (overwriting any same-named variables that were already there).

4) Thus normal visibility is one-way -- IPython sees the results of the scripts that you ran, so you can work with them more at the prompt, but your scripts don't see the results of previous scripts that you ran (not even the same script), or of anything you do at the prompt.

5) There is one huge difference, though, from when you run your script in plain Python. Namely, IPython itself is not re-initialized between runs (unless you reset the kernel), and in particular, any modules that have been imported are still initialized and won't be re-loaded or re-initialized when you import them in subsequent scripts. For more info, see [this article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart).

6) A side note: The %run command can be given a `-i` option to make namespace visibility 2-way, so your scripts will start in the IPython namespace (as I think you were expecting), but this is unusual and not the default, since usually one wants to ensure (as you apparently do) that the script is running "clean". The main reason to use this option would be to have your scripts build on each other, but there are more robust, portable ways to achieve this (namely passing variable names from the IPython namespace as parameters to the functions that you define in your script).

Comment: Oh wow! It all makes sense now. Thank you very much for your answer. I thought that the global namespace was shared between the console and any script I was running. This is makes complete sense now. Thanks again.